# Finding index of a first NON-NA for a specific column in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with multiple columns. Some of the data is missing (NA). I sorted the data frame by one column, and now the data is sorted properly but NA's are sorted as last values.
I want to get the index of the last non-na value.

```
column1 column2
1       2
2       na
3       some data
4       some data
na      some data
na      some data
na      some data
```

So I want to get the index of 4.
I tried

```
which(is.na(DF))
```

but it doesn't seem to return na values.

Comment: Do you just mean `which(is.na(DF$column1))[1]-1` ?  This is probably a duplicate -- have you searched for `[r] first NA value` ?  This is a little confusing because it seems your title doesn't match your question.

Comment: I think he wants `max(which(!is.na(DF$column1)))` or `max(which(complete.cases(DF$column1)))`.  Surely this is a duplicate of a bunch of things.

Comment: "na" isn't the same as NA.  Does your data really have na or is it NA?

Comment: It is represented as Not Available

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to convert all current "Not Available" entries in your data to `NA` so R will handle those entries as it should in subsequent operations. Otherwise, for example in your sample data, column1 could not be `numeric` because you have strings ("na") in the same column.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you want this expression:

```
max(which(complete.cases(DF$column1)))
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it returns the last row of the DF, not the last row of non-na column1 value

Comment: Then the last row does not have `NA` in this column.

Comment: Hm, beginner question: In my DF na values are represented as
Not Available. Does R look at this as NA as well or it's a normal string for R ? If so, I can try to look for last integer, since the data is only integers for that column

Comment: how about reading the data with `read.table(..., na.strings="Not Available")` ?

Answer (score 3):

I was attracted to this thread because I needed to find the first non-NA in each column of a data frame. Even though the original question is actually about finding the last non-NA in a column, I was able to figure out how to find the first non-NA from others' answers. I listed both below in case someone is wondering about the same thing.

Here is sample data. Notice that the columns should have been sorted with NAs at the beginning or end of each column.

```
(df <- data.frame(c=c(NA,NA,13,14,15), 
             d=c(16,17,NA,NA,NA), 
             e=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
             f=c(18,19,20,21,22)))
   c  d  e  f
1 NA 16 NA 18
2 NA 17 NA 19
3 13 NA NA 20
4 14 NA NA 21
5 15 NA NA 22
```

Two ways to find the first non-NA in each column. First is to use a for loop

```
x1 <- vector("numeric")
for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
  x1[j]<-df[,j] [min(which(!is.na(df[,j])))]
}

> x1
[1] 13 16 NA 18
```

Or use sapply. complete.cases does the same thing as !is.na on vectors.

```
(x2 <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(df)), function(x) df[,x] [min(which(!is.na(df[,x])))]))
[1] 13 16 NA 18
(x3 <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(df)), function(x) df[,x] [min(which(complete.cases(df[,x])))]))
[1] 13 16 NA 18
```

Similarly, there are two ways to find the last non-NA.

```
y1 <- vector("numeric")
for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
  y1[j] <- df[,j][max(which(!is.na(df[,j])))]
}
> y1
[1] 15 17 NA 22

(y2 <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(df)), function(x) df[,x] [max(which(!is.na(df[,x])))]))
[1] 15 17 NA 22
(y3 <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(df)), function(x) df[,x] [max(which(complete.cases(df[,x])))]))
[1] 15 17 NA 22
```

Based on my testing, the two methods have similar speed.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful.  Your code to find first NA in each column can be simplified to:  `sapply(d, function(col) min(which(!is.na(col)) ) )`
(I.e. `lapply` and variations applied to a `data.frame` iterate through the columns by default.)

Comment: Trying to use this with dplyr and a dataframe but getting an error "only defined on a data frame with all numeric-alike variables"